# Is HTML5's Canvas API Rotate or Translate function better?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

After a short discussion with a friend on a Canvas project, we realized that there is no clear cut answer on whether the Canvas **rotate** or **translate** functions are better to use. Mainly we want to know which is the best for rendering performance and why.

PS The save and restore method for rotating images across the net is terrible...

Comment: Rotation and translation are different, so why compare them?

Comment: Trying to figure out how to optimize rotations.

Answer (score 0):

Since they both boil down to matrix transforms, and "translate" is performed as merely an offset, presumably the translation would yield better performance in general than most types of rotation because there are simply more operations involved with a rotation than translation. See [Transformation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix), [Translation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_matrix) and [Rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) for some background.

But since the two aren't interchangeable in any way, shape or form, I fail to see the fruit of the debate.

Also, I feel that I should add since there is a general movement toward hardware acceleration for canvas related features in general, that the cost of any transformation may end up as a constant (eg. no actual cost) due to co-processor parallelism in the rendering pipeline...